# Excel macro only works when I have the sheet selected

Tags: excel, vba

Help! This macro works find when I have the "item inventory" sheet selected. Otherwise I get an 400 error. When stepping through I get a 1004 error on the first sort line.

```
Sub ItemInventorySort()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim lastrow As Long

Sheets("item inventory").Sort.SortFields.Clear

lastrow = Sheets("item inventory").Range("A1").End(xlDown).row

Sheets("item inventory").Range("A2:L" & CStr(lastrow)).Sort key1:=Range("F1"), order1:=xlAscending
Sheets("item inventory").Range("A2:L" & CStr(lastrow)).Sort key1:=Range("L1"), order1:=xlAscending

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to qualify the worksheet before `Range("F1")` and `Range("L1")`.

Comment: ahh thank you. sorry for the beginner bs.